# Python - issues with return in function

Tags: python, return, iteration

I'm using a csv (csv_f) that is basically just single quoted, comma separated words:

```
'foo','bar','yada', 'foo'
'test'
```

I'm trying to look each of these up in another document (csv_g) that looks like this:

```
1 'foo'
2 'bar'
3 'something'
4 'test'
```

And use this to build sparse vectors of the format

```
SparseVector(#lines in csv_g, [#s in first column of csv_g], [# of occurences of each in csv_f])
```

The examples above would look like this:

```
(4, [1, 2], [2, 1])
(4, [4], [1])
```

I've been chewing on this for a while and tried a few different approaches, but they all are not working. I'm not even trying to handle multiple occurences like 'foo' above yet. My closest approach has been this:

```
import csv

f = open(r'/path/to/csv_f.txt')
g = open(r'/path/to/csv_g.txt')
csv_f = csv.reader(f)
csv_g = csv.reader(g, delimiter=' ')

def lookup(text):
    for row_g in csv_g:
        if row_g[1] == text:
            return (row_g[0])
            break

for row_f in csv_f:
    positions = []
    counts = []
    size = len(row_f)
    i=0
    for i in range(size):
        fword = row_f[i]
        positions.append(lookup(fword))
        counts.append(1)
    print(positions, counts)
```

Running this has been resulting in:

```
[None, None, None, None] [1, 1, 1, 1]
[None] [1]
```

I'm confused why the function is returning None instead of the matches. I thought it'd hit the match, return it, and exit...

I also tried some nested loops without defining the lookup function (I can post these attempts if it helps, for now I didn't want to clutter your screens), but that hasn't been working either. I think this may be because generators only can be searched through once, but I'm not too sure.

Any hints on the best approach for this, and why the return isn't working as expected, would be extremely appreciated.

Comment: A few hints: you may only be able to loop through an open csv file once. If you loop through it again, it won't iterate at all. So you want to parse your entire `csv_g` file once, at first, making a dict of it or something. Then you look stuff up in the dict while iterating through `csv_f`. Also try printing out stuff at various spots (e.g. print row_g, print text) to help yourself debug what is going on.

Comment: `lookup` is returning None's because you are not matching anything, have you added some prints to see what is happening in the loop?

Comment: Thanks both! Claudiu i will try this. Padriac, printing elements from both csv's return the same quoted strings when I expect it to, let me think of a good way to edit the post above to show this.

Comment: @GeorgeO, If your question is now solved, you should post an answer to your own question, and then accept it. This will clear your question out of the unanswered questions here at Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out by doing what Claudiu and Padriac suggested. Updated code:

```
import csv

f = open(r'/path/to/csv_f.txt')
g = open(r'/path/to/csv_g.txt')
csv_f = csv.reader(f)
csv_g = csv.reader(g, delimiter=' ')

dict = []

for row_g in csv_g:
    dict.append(row_g)
for row_f in csv_f:
    positions = []
    counts = []
    size = len(row_f)
    i=0
    while i<size:
        fword = row_f[i]
        for line in dict:
            gword = line[1]
            if fword == gword:
                positions.append(line[0])
                counts.append(1)
                break
        i+=1
    print(positions, counts)
```

I'm not sure why the lookup function wasn't getting matches, but I'm just happy I was able to get something working finally!